# vb.net class reloads when a subroutine is classed from another class

Tags: vb.net, class, reload

My vb.net program loads with ClassA. During program run, i call a Class B that makes some processes. during ClassB processing , it call a subroutine into ClassA (Main program form class), but when i do this , i found that the whole initialization of the class A occurs again, ie, the DECLARATION of class variables starts again, and the NEW subroutine occurs again.

**- NB : This only occurs if I run Class B from a backgroundworker. If
   ClassB was called from Form1 Main Thread, this error does not appear.**

here is the code :

```
Public Class Form1
Dim g As String = "adsfadsf"

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim clsB As New ClassB
    clsB.st()
End Sub
Public Sub UpdateView()
    ' do update here
End Sub
End Class


Public Class ClassB
Public Sub st()
    Form1.UpdateView()
End Sub
End Class
```

Any feedback ?

---

It seems that background worker is the issue since it loses reference to the parent thread. A workaround it's to pass  A reference to the main thread, then use this reference to call the specific subroutine
I tried out and worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code? (Can't add a comment yet :/).

You might be declaring a new instance of ClassA every time you make a reference in ClassB routine.

What you can do, if ClassA is some sort of module which stores common functions is just use its as a Shared class and Shared methods, if it is the real problem.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and here [mcve] .. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: No problem. Adding your code made it much easier to figure out what was wrong.